# Rationale for box-constrained optimization in adversarial example search

Tags: machine-learning, constrained-optimization, adversarial-example

In Section 4.1 of ["Intriguing properties of neural networks" by Szegedy et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6199), the authors define the optimization problem they solve to find *adversarial examples* in a deep neural network. I am a bit puzzled by the second constraint: why is it necessary to require (2) $x+r \in [0,1]^m$?

The authors say that solutions $r$ to such optimization problem yield $x+r$ the closest data point to $x$ that is classified by $f$ to a class different than $f(x)$. I don't see the role that constraint (2) plays in this. They state that $x\in\mathbb R^m$, so $x+r$ should also be in $\mathbb R^m$.